# How do I make an NSView move to the front of all NSViews

Tags: cocoa, xcode, nsview

How do I make an NSView window move up to the front.  My app has 3 windows and when I press a button in one of them I want another to move on top of this one.

Comment: "NSView window" is a bit confusing. Perhaps you mean NSWindow? If so, the answer by @psychotik below is a good pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`makeKeyAndOrderFront:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/makeKeyAndOrderFront:), perhaps?